# how to auto config load-balancing in rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing

i have been following the steps from http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html but i keep getting

Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@devimgng6: nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on devimgng6: [{rabbitmqctl6692,54998}]
- current node: rabbitmqctl6692@devimgng6
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: sZNFGhyjURtfF+vOwxl9NA==

my rabbitmq.config is:

```
 [
      {rabbit, [
          {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@devimgng6', 'rabbit@devimgng6'], disc}}
      ]}
  ].
```

and i checked that in the .erlang.cookie i hava the same string/
what am i doing wrong? maybe someone can refer me to a different tutorial?

EDIT:

i fixed my config file to:

```
[
      {rabbit, [
          {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@devimgng6', 'rabbit@devimgng1'], disc}}
      ]}
  ].
```

i'm using 2 host named: devimgng6 and devimgng1. i stoped each host using rabbitmqctl stop_app/reset/stop as the tutorial says, added the config file under /etc/rabbitmq and started the rabbitmq-server
i'm still getting the same error as before. ideas?

thanks

Comment: Provide your question with more info. How many hosts you are using for clustering? What are their names? Which line of the tutorial provide error? And all the commands you typed before and its output.

Comment: see my question edit.

Comment: Did you try to build cluster manually with rabbitmctl (without config file)? What was the result?

Comment: when i tried manually i got this error: dev@devimgng1:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster \rabbit@devimgng6 \rabbit@devimgng1
Clustering node rabbit@devimgng1 with [rabbit@devimgng6,rabbit@devimgng1] ...
Error: {no_running_cluster_nodes,[rabbit@devimgng6],[rabbit@devimgng6]}

Comment: What is OS and the version of RabbitMQ you are using? Does RabbitMQ start successfully without clustering on both nodes?

Comment: As RabbitMQ starts normally on both nodes without clustering, probably nodes can't connect each other because of DNS settings (devimgng6 knows nothing about devimgng1) or because of firewall settings. Try to `ping devimgng1` from devimgng6 host and vice versa.

Comment: i'm using ubuntu and rabbitmq 2.7.1 and it starts successfully without clustering on both nodes

Comment: it works fine:64 bytes from devimgng1 (10.0.110.34): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.360 ms and 64 bytes from devimgng6 (10.0.110.39): icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.533 ms

Comment: To ensure your nodes use the same cookie and no other network problems try to do the following steps: on devimgng1 from linux shell: `erl -setcookie YOUR_RABBITMQ_COOKIE_STRING -sname test` and then from started Erlang shell: `net_adm:ping('rabbit@devimgng1').` you should get `pong` response. This mean that RabbitMQ and started Erlang shell use the same cookie. Do the same on devimgng6. And then try to call `net_adm:ping('rabbit@devimgng1').` from devimgng6 created test Erlang shell. You shoul get `pong`. Try it.